# Phonegap: i can't find my sqlite database on android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I try to create my first Phonegap app. My previous experience with mobile developing was an android application. 
I create finally a database and store some data inside with above code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("LIST", "1.0", "LIST Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Now i try to find my Database on emulator (as i read in many posts) in this path:

/data/data/{package_name}/database

or in

/data/data/{package_name}/app_database

but nothing there. I only found the above databases

```
webview.db
webview.db-shm
webview.db-wal
webviewCookiesChromium.db
webviewCookiesChromiumPrivate.db
```

All this database i can't pull them from emulator to see what have inside.
Where i can find my database?
I expect to find something in there like LIST.DB but nothing. Right?

Comment: What are you using sqllite or websql ?

Comment: I am using websql. I found the database finally. Is in path /data/data/{package name}/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db and inside in this database someone will find the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve what you are finding.

In eclipse, go to DDMS perspective --> File Explorer  --> data  --> data  --> your package  --> databases

Answer (score 0):

In the "onDeviceReady()" function you can  use:

if(!dbcreate){
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("001010101010", "1.0", "My_Database", -1);
}

```
And for load file:
```

File dbFile = getDatabasePath(".001010101010.db");
The DB file needs to be in the next route:

yourProyect/assets/001010101010.db.

you can also check more about sqllite : http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i have a question, why to use sqlitePlugin instead of normal db create? Which is the use of it?

Comment: you can also use websql instead of sqllite if you are using phonegap .