# Not able to create Database in Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I am not able to create Database in Phonegap for Android.

**Note** : I am testing on Genymotion.

Below are the solutions that I tried :

- [Using PhoneGap for Android : Not able to create table in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740595/using-phonegap-for-android-not-able-to-create-table-in-the-database)
- [Creating SQLite Table from Android HTML Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499899/creating-sqlite-table-from-android-html-assets?rq=1)
- [Phonegap: i can't find my sqlite database on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071471/phonegap-i-cant-find-my-sqlite-database-on-android-emulator)

Below is my code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);      
}

function populateDB(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
```

I am referring Cordova 3.1.0 version docs : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database

I tried to find my Database(*test.db*) on emulator from this path:

```
/data/data/{package_name}/database
```

or in

```
/data/data/{package_name}/app_database
```

but it does not show *test.db* database.

*Do I need to include anything in config.xml file?*

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get the base path with

```
<Context>.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
```

And then append:

- For KitKat and higher: `/app_webview/databases/file__0/1`
- For older versions: `/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db`